# Ruby inheritance loop

Tags: ruby, api, inheritance, parent-child

In the Ruby 1.9.2 Core API Reference, it says that Object's parent is BasicObject. But then it says that BasicObject's parent is Object. How does this work? What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That must be a bug in the documentation. Conceptually, `BasicObject` doesn't have a parent, practically, this is represented by its parent being `nil`. (Note: `nil`, the *object*, not `NilClass`.)

Note that on [RubyDoc.Info](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/BasicObject/), it is correctly shown as having no parent.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that Object's parent is BasicObject, but BasicObject's parent is not Object.

```
Object.ancestors # => [Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
BasicObject.ancestors # => [BasicObject]
```

Comment: I installed Ruby using the Windows 1.9.2 installer from ruby-lang.org. In the install directory there was a doc folder, with a ruby19-core.chm. This reference is where I saw my issue.

Comment: I didn't have that version of reference. As Jorg writes, it must be a bug in the documentation.

Comment: @Adam Harte: Actually, it's probably a bug in the documentation *processor*. As I wrote in my answer, [RubyDoc.Info](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/BasicObject/), which is generated using [YARD](http://YARDoc.Org/), is fine, so the fault probably lies with [RDoc](http://RDoc.RubyForge.Org/). After all, the inheritance relationships of `Object` and `BasicObject` don't actually show up in Ruby source code (because, at least in YARV, from which the CHM files are generated, they don't *have* a Ruby source, they are implemented in C), which means they must be somehow hardcoded inside RDoc itself.